# CQRS & Event Sourcing way to handle a single request that needs to generate multiple commands

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am making a genealogy application as I am trying to learn Event Sourcing and CQRS. I have three aggregates in my application: PersonAggregate, FactAggregate, FamilyAggregate.
My request from the UI to the Server to add a spouse to a person is:

```
{
  personId: "", // And Existing Person in the DB
  personInput: {name: "Bob", birthDate: ""} // Input to create a new person in the DB
}
```

My Family Aggregate listens to the PersonAggregate for events of `PersonCreated` to keep a record of all people that have been created.

Would it be a good architecture for the UI to call the PersonAggregate to create the person (with the data about it needing to create a partnership between the two people instead of calling the FamilyAggregate), then on the `PersonCreated` event to put the data the FamilyAggregate will need to know to add the two people as spouses? Or is that a bad design because now the Event has command data in it?

When a person is created, the Person Aggregate also needs to send data to the FactAggregate to create a Fact about the person's birthdate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The need to update multiple aggregates in a single transaction is a sign that aggregate boundaries are wrong. Because an aggregate is responsible for protecting a transaction boundary by definition. And a single event corresponds to a single transaction.

Let's consider how this case is handled in a non-computer world. The business domain is well designed there. Sharpened through centuries to be as robust and simple as it gets.

The point of decision is not a person or a family. It is the church. Metric book is the aggregate. When a priest makes up a decision, he writes it down into a metric book. Everything else - person's documents, genealogy, list of person's facts - are mere read models in the registration bounded context.

They can be aggregates in other bounded contexts. And some service may listen to registration events and update relevant entities after the original transaction is completed and event is written. Eventually.

Comment: So there with that example there might be a Metrical Service that gets called and records MarriageRegistered or NewPersonRegsitered. Then the Person service listens for that and records the data it needs and a family would listen for a marriageregistered to record the two as being married?

Comment: Yes something like this. PersonNameGiven and PersonDied, probably. Then Genealogy service could store the data in the graph representation and efficiently answer queries about a person's family tree. But then what queries would the Person service answer? And another question is: what a priest validates about the data before making a record? I.e. what should be validated.

Comment: Probably in a genealogy service it could be checked that a person only can add a record about a person, who is connected to him...

Comment: But does that mean that the Metrical Service then has to verify the birth and death events that were passed in were valid? Or PersonName has is valid input? when those should be in the person and fact boundary respectively?

Comment: What is a valid birth event? Anyway, this event should give start to a person's existence. As for a death event - it can be validated, that only that who had been born, died. And no other events for this person should be allowed. Then any person (or any person's life facts) can be reconstructed from this records. A person could be identified by a full name, date and place of birth. Metrical service could also validate birth events for duplicates.